# Mocking CloudStorageAccount and CloudTable for Azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, mocking, azure-table-storage

So I am trying to test Azure Table Storage and mock things that I depend on. My class is structured in a way that I establish a connection in the constructor, i.e. I create a new instance of `CloudStorageAccount` in which I create an instance of `StorageCredentials` that has `storageName` and `storageKey`. Afterwards, I create an instance of `CloudTable`, which I use further in the code to perform CRUD operations. My class looks as follows:

```
public class AzureTableStorageService : ITableStorage
{
        private const string _records = "myTable";
        private CloudStorageAccount _storageAccount;
        private CloudTable _table;

        public AzureTableStorageService()
        {
            _storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(
                 ConfigurationManager.azureTableStorageName, ConfigurationManager.azureTableStorageKey), true);
            _table = _storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(_records);
            _table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        }

        //...
        //Other methods here
}
```

`_table` is reused throughout the class for different purposes. My goal is to mock it, but since it is virtual and doesn't implement any interface, I can't come over with a simple `Mock` solution like:

```
_storageAccount = new Mock<CloudStorageAccount>(new Mock<StorageCredentials>(("dummy", "dummy"), true));
_table  = new Mock<CloudTable>(_storageAccount.Object.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(_records));
```

Therefore, when I try to construct my Unit Test in this way I am getting:
`Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class.`

My goal is to accomplish something like:

```
_table.Setup(x => x.DoSomething()).ReturnsAsync("My desired result");
```

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: I am looking at the API and the class is not sealed and all of the methods in this example are in fact virtual. So I can't really provide an example on how to fix this because to me there doesn't seem to be any issue. I also don't really see how you can feasibly mock out the dependencys in this example. You really should be using a factory object to provide the table and pass it in via the constructor. That way there's only one line of code and far easier to replace in UnitTesting.

Comment: @Ambidex sorry for a confusion, any ideas on Mocking it?

Comment: I edited my previous comment. Basically in this scenario I'd suggest using a factory to create the table and then have it passed in via the constructor of the TableStorage class.  All of the classes in this example allow being mocked and have virtual methods. https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method

Comment: @Ambidex that seems to be straight forward approach, I am looking for ways to Mock it as it is, without changing the class behavior. I am wondering if it is possible. Thanks for clarification, appreciate it!

Comment: Your class is tightly coupled to implementation concerns that make it difficult to unit test in isolation. The current design of the class under test would probably work in an integration test but that would require actually connecting to an actual cloud service. The constructor of the class is also misleading about what its dependencies are with only the logger explicitly injected. Note that in the majority of cases, the level of difficulty encountered when trying to test a class directly reflects how clean the design was.

Comment: All those cloud related concerns should be treated as 3rd party external dependencies and abstracted out.

Comment: Try something like [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Azure.Data.Wrappers). It are wrappers around the real thing providing interfaces upou can mock.

Comment: i have similar behavior, adding a comment to follow it up

Comment: @Nkosi, do you have a better design of this. I understand when you say its tightly coupled, but would you be able to provide an example of this with loose coupling

Comment: @Coke, did you get your answer, if yes please share it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was also struggling with implementing unit test for an Azure Function with a binding to Azure Table Storage. I got it finally working using a derived CloudTable class where I can override the methods I use and return fixed results.

```
/// <summary>
/// Mock class for CloudTable object
/// </summary>
public class MockCloudTable : CloudTable
{

    public MockCloudTable(Uri tableAddress) : base(tableAddress)
    { }

    public MockCloudTable(StorageUri tableAddress, StorageCredentials credentials) : base(tableAddress, credentials)
    { }

    public MockCloudTable(Uri tableAbsoluteUri, StorageCredentials credentials) : base(tableAbsoluteUri, credentials)
    { }

    public async override Task<TableResult> ExecuteAsync(TableOperation operation)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(new TableResult
        {
            Result = new ScreenSettingEntity() { Settings = "" },
            HttpStatusCode = 200
        });
    }
}
```

I instantiated the mock class by passing an configuration string used for local storage by the storage emulator (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string).

```
var mockTable = new MockCloudTable(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/screenSettings"));
```

In this example 'screenSettings' is the name of the table.

The mock class can now be passed to the Azure Function from your unit test.

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, this solution works fine for me. I just had to add an Etag property to "Result" because my function does an update on the table.

Comment: This is a great answer. The Uri format was what I had issues with. Once I got that correct I was able to create a stub with NSubstitute without subclassing.

If you are trying to mock `TableQuerySegment<T>`, there is a workable technique here https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/619#issuecomment-364090291

Comment: @wilco, is it really using the mocking framework or just this MockCloudTable? Would you be able to tell it by using MOQ

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer here, as you're aiming to use a mocking framework, simply setting up an object that inherits from CloudTable and provides a default constructor should allow you to Mock the inherited object itself and control what it returns:

```
public class CloudTableMock : CloudTable
{
    public CloudTableMock() : base(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/screenSettings"))
    {
    }
}
```

Then it's just a case of creating the mock.  I'm using NSubstitute so I did:

```
_mockTable = Substitute.For<CloudTableMock>();
```

but my guess is that Moq would allow:

```
_mockTableRef = new Mock<CloudTable>();
_mockTableRef.Setup(x => x.DoSomething()).ReturnsAsync("My desired result");
_mockTable = _mockTableRef.Object;
```

(My Moq is a bit rusty, so I'm guessing the syntax above isn't quite correct)

Comment: would you be able to add a working example. As this is Just a reference and I am not able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same scenario as the selected answer involving an Azure function with table binding. There are some limitations to using a mock `CloudTable` especially when using `System.Linq` with `CreateQuery<T>` for example as those are extension methods on `IQueryable`.

A better approach is to use a `HttpMessageHandler` mock such as *RichardSzalay.MockHttp* with `TableClientConfiguration.RestExecutorConfiguration.DelegatingHandler` and then just stubbing out the json response you'd expect from the table.

```
public class Azure_Function_Test_With_Table_Binding
{
    [Fact]
    public void Should_be_able_to_stub_out_a_CloudTable()
    {
        var storageAccount = StorageAccount.NewFromConnectionString("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
        var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        var mockedRequest = new MockHttpMessageHandler()
            .When("http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/pizzas*")
            .Respond("application/json", 
            @"{
                ""value"": [
                    {
                        ""Name"": ""Pepperoni"",
                        ""Price"": 9.99
                    }
                ]
            }");

        client.TableClientConfiguration.RestExecutorConfiguration.DelegatingHandler = new MockedRequestAdapter(mockedRequest);
        var table = client.GetTableReference("pizzas");

        var request = new DefaultHttpContext().Request;
        request.Query = new QueryCollection(new Dictionary<string, StringValues> { { "Pizza", new StringValues("Pepperoni") } });

        var result = PizzaStore.Run(request, table, null);

        Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
    }
}

public class MockedRequestAdapter : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly MockedRequest _mockedRequest;

    public MockedRequestAdapter(MockedRequest mockedRequest) : base()
    {
        _mockedRequest = mockedRequest;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _mockedRequest.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(request.Method, request.RequestUri), cancellationToken);
    }
}

public static class PizzaStore
{
    [FunctionName("PizzaStore")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [Table("pizzas", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] CloudTable cloud,
        ILogger log)
    {
        if (req.Query.TryGetValue("Pizza", out var value))
        {
            var pizza = cloud.CreateQuery<Pizza>().Where(p => p.Name == value.ToString()).SingleOrDefault();

            return new OkObjectResult(new { Pizza = pizza.Name, Price = pizza.Price });
        }

        return new NotFoundResult();
    }
}

public class Pizza : TableEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation:

```
 public class StorageServiceTest
{
   IStorageService _storageService;
    Mock<CloudStorageAccount> _storageAccount;
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var c = new StorageCredentials("dummyStorageAccountName","DummyKey");
       _storageAccount = new Mock<CloudStorageAccount>(c, true);
        _storageService = new StorageService(_storageAccount.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCase("ax0-1s", "random-1")]
    public void get_content_unauthorized(string containerName,string blobName)
    {
        //Arrange
        string expectOutputText = "Something on the expected blob";
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://somethig.com//");
        var blobClientMock = new Mock<CloudBlobClient>(uri);
        _storageAccount.Setup(a => a.CreateCloudBlobClient()).Returns(blobClientMock.Object);

        var cloudBlobContainerMock = new Mock<CloudBlobContainer>(uri);
        blobClientMock.Setup(a => a.GetContainerReference(containerName)).Returns(cloudBlobContainerMock.Object);

        var cloudBlockBlobMock = new Mock<CloudBlockBlob>(uri);
        cloudBlobContainerMock.Setup(a => a.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName)).Returns(cloudBlockBlobMock.Object);

        cloudBlockBlobMock.Setup(a => a.DownloadTextAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(expectOutputText));

        //Act
       var actual = _storageService.DownloadBlobAsString(containerName, blobName);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(actual.Result));
        Assert.AreEqual(actual.Result, expectOutputText);
    }
}
```

Service class implementation:

```
 Task<string> IStorageService.DownloadBlobAsString(string containerName, string blobName)
    {
        var blobClient = this.StorageAccountClient.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

        var blobReference = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        var blobContentAsString = blobReference.DownloadTextAsync();

        return blobContentAsString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using classes from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` namespace, using NSubstitute it is relatively easy to create mocks, e.g.:

```cs
var mockStorageAccount = Substitute.For<CloudStorageAccount>(
  CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount.Credentials,
  false);
var mockQueueClient = Substitute.For<CloudQueueClient>(
  mockStorageAccount.QueueStorageUri,
  mockStorageAccount.Credentials);
```

etc.